# CATIA Macro "Any geometry infinite"

Tags: vb.net, catia

I am trying to measure distance between a line and a point using below code.

```
ptref = Partdocument.Part.CreateReferenceFromObject(pt1) 'creating reference from point
    refline = Partdocument.Part.CreateReferenceFromObject(line1) 'creating reference from line
```

Get measure

```
 TheMeasurable = TheSPAWorkbench.GetMeasurable(refline)
    dist1 = TheMeasurable.GetMinimumDistance(ptref)
```

since line and point are at different plane, I am not getting the required output.
I want to to measure using "`Any geometry, infinite option`".

Please suggest how I can incorporate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not supported using the SPAWorkbench/Measurable.

As a workaround, it is not difficult to get the end points of the line and perform the calculation using vector algebra.